# 401.2 error when trying to authenticate with a client certificate

Tags: c#, httpclient, client-certificates

I'm trying to authenticate to a website using client certificates from a .net application.

Using the same certificate I can access the site using chrome and IE. On the same machine I get the error status code 401.2.

This is the code I'm using:

```
X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(x509Cert);
cert2.PrivateKey = algorithm;

if (cert2.Verify() && cert2.HasPrivateKey)
{
    WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert2);
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

    string result = await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:8443/");
}
```

EDIT:

I have now tried extracting the same certificate that the browsers use from the certificate store, but I still get the same error, and I have switched to using the older WebClient, again I get the same error.

Any clues would be appreciated!

Thanks

Ross

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't my code, it was an IIS config issue.

Browsers were working because they were also sending my windows credentials - my app wasn't doing this which is why it failed.

I had to enable mapping client certificates to AD: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/clientcertificatemappingauthentication

Then I had to disable windows auth on the site. The application then works as expected.